# VSCODE - TAB right after the word not working as expected

Tags: visual-studio-code

vscode: 
version - 1.40.2

On a normal text type file, type Hello and hit <kbd>TAB</kbd>.

All i want is when i hit tab vscode should register 2/4 spaces (what i have configured in the settings.json for the specific language) not a single space.

`Hello`<kbd>TAB</kbd>

Expected: `Hello****|`
Actual: `Hello*|`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have unchecked `Editor: Detect Indentation`. Checking this option will override the `Tab Size` configuration. E.g. if the opened file has 1 space tab indentation but you have configured a 4 spaces tab indentation - the tab size will be 1 space.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> to open `Settings.json`
- Enter in "spaces" in search
- Uncheck `Editor: Detect Indentation`
- Leave `Editor: Insert spaces` checked if you want to insert actual spaces instead of a tab (i.e. you need to do 4 backspaces if you made a mistake). Or unchecked it if you want to insert actual tabs.

[image: Example demo]

Also, you can check what is the configured tab size for that particular opened file by looking at the **bottom right** of your editor:

[image]

Comment: Appreciate the effort but i am afraid above settings are not working for me.